# Select a location with radius with click and drag in google maps api

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I want to be able to select a radius of 1m - 5km with click and drag action. The click and drag should draw a circle that is limited to 5km radius.

Can someone help me or at least put me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should have googled more before asking this question.

Great tutorial here: https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/mvcfun?hl=sv